# Outline on dropdown select - cannot remove :(

Tags: css

I'm using Firefox and cannot seem to get rid of the outline around a selected option.

**My code**

*HTML*

```
        <div class="drop-select">
             <select name="date" id="date">
               <option value="01">01</option>
               <option value="02">02</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Pretty straightforward.

*CSS*

```
.drop-select {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font: 12px/14px arial, helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
    width: 80px;
    height:25px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url('http://www.adcentre.com.au/media/1326/bg-down-arrow.gif')no-repeat right #fff;
   float: left;
   margin-right: 5px;
   margin-top: 6px;
   margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.drop-select select {
   background: transparent;
   width: 125px;
   height: 25px;
   border: none;
   padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
   color: #000;
   outline:0;
}
```

Even with me setting the outline to 0 and border to none, it still displays it?

Example in JSFiddle:

http://bit.ly/SpQGC4

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news - that's the state of affairs with the option and select elements. They still retain OS styling. Afaik, the only way to style them consistently cross-browser, is to emulate them - i.e use a non-standard control. These are typically constructed using a bunch of divs or an unordered list. Same as radio-buttons and check-boxes and scroll-bars. They're all OS ui elements, and as such retain any styling imparted _by the os_ on them.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the dropdown's parent, `div.drop-select`, has a black `border`. Remove that, and the black border will disappear.

Don't confuse `outline` with `border`; in many browsers, `outline` defines the glow that, for example, a text input field gets on focus (as I write this answer in Safari, the text box has a blue outline with a slight blur). Border refers to something much like an outline, but generally used on things *other* than form elements, and generally present in all element states, rather than just `focus`.

It's also worth mentioning that, in some browsers, both on Windows and Mac OS (not sure about Linux distros), the outline of form elements *can* be styled.

Comment: I guess he wants to remove the outline from select **OPTION** list

Comment: It's actually gone on my system, at least, in the browsers I've installed (Safari, Firefox, and Chrome). Suppose this could be a cross-platform/cross-browser issue?